# Is there a way to watch for balance?

Tags: accounts, javascript-sdk

How can I programmatically watch for change in balance for a account or just new incoming transactions?

looking for [`js-stellar-sdk`](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/index.html) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just got this from [another answer](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/examples.html#streaming-payment-events).

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk')
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org');

// Get a message any time a payment occurs. Cursor is set to "now" to be notified
// of payments happening starting from when this script runs (as opposed to from
// the beginning of time).
var es = server.payments()
  .cursor('now')
  .stream({
    onmessage: function (message) {
      console.log(message);
    }
  })
```

To watch for a particular account you may try

```
var es = server.transactions()
    .forAccount(accountAddress)
    .cursor(lastCursor)
    .stream({
        onmessage: txHandler
    })
```

as explained [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/reference/index.html#streaming-requests)

Comment: did you ever get streaming balance data? The above is good example of streaming but the balance question remains.